# Invalid Syntax error while installing Django in linux

Tags: python, django, linux, django-rest-framework, terminal

I am trying to install Django in linux version x86.I have already installed python.
Error I am getting when executed "pip install Django" or "pip3 install Django"

```sh
$ pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mandar/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/mandar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What distro are you running, and is this arm, x86, or x64? Please put more information into your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**:

I suggest you to upgrade Python to a newer version as other user has adviced.
This is because **f-string** was added form Python 3.6 on, check [this](http://f-Strings:%20A%20New%20and%20Improved%20Way%20to%20Format%20Strings%20in%20Python).

- [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

---

1. Step 1:- Install ppa:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   ```
2. Update packeges:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Upgrade python 2.x to python 3.6 or higher

   ```
    sudo apt-get install python3.6
   ```
4. PiP installation:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-pip
   ```

---

Upgrade pip first (which also upgrades setuptools) and then install django again:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install django
```

Or:

```
pip install --upgrade pip 
pip install django
```

Alternative 2:

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force setuptools
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
sudo pip install django==3.1
```

**EDIT**: As @Ronald Petit stated,keep this in mind:

> Django 3.0+ requires python 3.6+ and you are using python 3.5, you need to either update to a newer python (recommended), or specify Django version to be 2.2 (really not recommended)

hence Run

```
pip install django==2.2
```

Comment: actually pip command isnt working , both alternative are giving same error ,I tried to uninstall pip but it is also giving me same error

Comment: actually pip command is not working its giving same syntax errors, even pip version command isn't working

Comment: python-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.

Comment: That's really Cool ;)

Answer (score 2):

Django 3.0+ requires python 3.6+ and you are using python 3.5, you need to either update to a newer python (recommended), or specify Django version to be 2.2 (really not recommended)

To install an specific django version just do:

```
pip install django==x.x.x
```

x.x.x can be replaced for example with 2.2

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support

Comment: @MandarRemane You must be still using python 3.5 as the error is marking an f string which is not available in python 3.5 but in 3.6

Comment: yeah error was solved! Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue caused by an outdated version of `setuptools (5.5.x)`.

When installing Django 1.9+ with `setuptools 5.5.x`, you’ll see this type of error.

It’s safe to ignore these errors (Django will still install just fine), but you can avoid them by upgrading `setuptools` to a more recent version. If you’re using pip, you can upgrade pip using `pip install -U pip` which will also upgrade `setuptools`.

The solution is to **upgrade pip** first (which also upgrades `setuptools`) and then install `Django` again:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install django
```

Answer (score 2):

Pip has already dropped support for Python2 (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/). I suggest you to use older version of Pip, or to switch to Python3.6.

Syntax error near fsting means that your env doesn't support fstings (it is introduced in Python3.6

--edit--

You can isntall Python with this tutorial: https://www.2daygeek.com/install-python-3-on-centos-6/